# How to hookup validations for a mongoid embedded resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a comments model embedded in a posts model:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :content, :type => String
  embeds_many :comments
end

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :content, :type => String
  validates_presence_of :content
  embedded_in :post, :inverse_of => :comments 
end
```

The comment form, as expected, is included in posts/show:

```
p#notice = notice

h2= @post.name
p= @post.content

a.btn href=edit_post_path(@post) Edit

h3 New comment
= simple_form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :content, :as => :text
  = f.button :submit
```

And in my comments controller:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])  
  @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment created.' }
    else
      format.html { render :template => "posts/show" }
    end
  end
end
```

This seems to work for valid comments, but has two problems for blank comments. First, no validation message is shown. Second, the blank comment is rendered in the post/show template because it is included in @post (even though it isn't persisted) after calling `@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])`.

The railscast on this topic uses `@post.comments.create!(params[:comment])` instead of build, but this leads to an exception on any validation failure which I don't think is appropriate.

I could get around the second problem by refetching the post, but this seems kludgy:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])  
  @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment created.' }
    else
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])  
      format.html { render :template => "posts/show" }
    end
  end
end
```

And even still, the validation is missing.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how this could be done better?

Comment: Probably the same solution as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046143/update-attributes-returns-always-true-even-if-nested-attributes-are-not-valid although I'm not sure what it is.